# Free-JqGrid : autowidth doesn't work in a Panel Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a jqGrid inside a Panel Bootstrap and i can't find why the `autowidth:true` parameter doesn't work. Here's the jqGrid code :

```
    grid.jqGrid({
        data: myData,
        datatype:'local',
        noDataContent: "Aucune données présente..",
        loadMessage: "Merci de patienter...",
        styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
        colNames: ["Liste des rubriques","Taux Sal","Taux Pat"],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: "Libelle", template: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: "txsalrub", template: 'integer',formatter:'number', formatoptions: {decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '0.00'}
            },
            {
                name: "txpatrub", template: 'integer',formatter:'number', formatoptions: {decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '0.00'}
            }
            ],
        // loadonce: true,
        autowidth:true,
        // width: 'auto',
        maxHeight: height
        // width: null,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        // cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
        // autoResizing: { compact: true },
        // autoresizeOnLoad: true
    });
```

And here is the result i have :

[Free JqGrid autowidth not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBdTj.png)

I have try many solution but nothing work :/

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). You write about "Free-JqGrid" in your message, but you use `styleUI : 'Bootstrap'` option instead of `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-bootstrap2.htm) as an example). It looks that you do use commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS instead of free jqGrid.

Comment: No no don't worry i use the Free JqGrid version 4.13.3 the styleUI is a mistake

Comment: Is the problem is solved now? If the problem is still exist, please provides the demo, which reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have made some workaround with width instead of autowidth and it's work. But if i can push my luck to have you.. I have a group column problem. I need to group every data from the same year and instead of grouping all line from year 2014 into one group, my grid make like 3 group of one line. I answer a new question to give you the code and the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code from my grid

```
var grid = $("#decompteUser");
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: myData })
            .trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1}]);
        grid.jqGrid({
            data: myData,
            datatype:'local',
            guiStyle: "bootstrap",
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            colNames: ["N°décompte","Nbj Payés","Brut Payé","Net Payé","Net Imposable","N° Chèque","Date", "Date Paiement"],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: "iddec", template: 'string'
                },
                {
                    name: "nbjpayedec", template: 'integer',formatter:'currency', formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 2, suffix: " J"}
                },
                {
                    name: "mtbrutdec", template: 'integer',formatter:'currency', formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 2, suffix: " €"}
                },
                {
                    name: "mtnetdec", template: 'integer',formatter:'currency', formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 2, suffix: " €"}
                },
                {
                    name: "mtnetimposdec", template: 'integer',formatter:'currency', formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 2, suffix: " €"}
                },
                {
                    name: "numchequedec", template: 'integer'
                },
                {
                    name: "dteditdec", template: 'string',formatter:'date', formatoptions:{srcformat: 'Y/m/d', newformat: 'd/m/Y'}
                },
                {
                    name: "dtpaiementdec", template: 'string',formatter:'date', formatoptions:{srcformat: 'Y/m/d', newformat: 'Y'}
                }
                ],
            maxHeight: height,
            width:width,
            grouping:true,
            groupingView: {
                groupField : ['dtpaiementdec'],
                groupOrder: 'desc',
                groupColumnShow : true,
                groupText: ['Année : <b>{0}</b>']
            }
        });
        $("#decompteUser").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'local'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

[Result of JqGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuZ46.png)